# Analog of Zend\Validate\Db\NoRecordExists in Symfony 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, symfony

In Zend Framework I can use beautiful validator `Zend\Validate\Db\NoRecordExists` to validate duplicate records. Are similar validator exists in Symfony 2 and how can I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Unique Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) in symfony to validate that a particular field in a model is unique.